# Angular: StaticInjectorError(ExplorationEditorPageModule)[String]

Tags: angularjs, angular, migration

I'm currently migrating oppia's codebase https://github.com/oppia/oppia from AngularJS(1.x) to Angular(2+). I migrated a service UtilsService.ts(https://github.com/oppia/oppia/blob/develop/core/templates/dev/head/services/UtilsService.ts) to following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilsService {
  isEmpty(obj: any): boolean {
    for (var property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  isString(input: any): boolean {
    return (typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String);
  }
}

angular.module('oppia').factory(
  'UtilsService',
  downgradeInjectable(UtilsService));
```

This service is used in whole lot of other services and directives. I'm getting this error when I start the app now.

```
StaticInjectorError(ExplorationEditorPageModule)[String]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:725:0)
    at resolveToken (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11917:0)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11861:0)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11763:0)
    at resolveToken (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11917:0)
    at tryResolveToken (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11861:0)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11763:0)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20233:0)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20904:0)
    at injectInjectorOnly (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:628:0)
    at URL: http://localhost:8181/create/hCByec28SLfx#/gui/Introduction
```

This is how the ExplorationEditorPageModule looks - https://github.com/oppia/oppia/blob/develop/core/templates/dev/head/pages/exploration-editor-page/exploration-editor-page.module.ts.

I'm stuck here and couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

The string in TypeScript needs to written in lower case, that is why your code fails

> isString(input: any): boolean {
>       return (typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String);   <--- here
>      }

maybe you should just switch around your checks and check for `typeof input === 'String' || input instanceof string`

The Error tries to tell you that 'String' is not a known type, which should not be suprising given the knowledge above.